# Confused accessing delegate from WPF ui thread

Tags: c#

My apologies but I can't see what I am doing wrong / not understanding? I have declared a delegate such as:

```
namespace ABC
{
   public delegate void GenerateView();

   public class X
   {
      public X()
      {
         GenerateView handler = GenerateViewMethod;
      }

      public void GenerateViewMethod()
      { .... }

    }
 }
```

Then in the ui I call it as such:

```
private readonly X MyXClass;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(MyXClass.???) //handler isn't an option?
```

The only method that shows is GenerateViewMethod and of course that isn't my delegate.

So obviously I am not exposing the delegate properly but I'm not clicking on what is missing.

Thank you for the assistance

---

Update further information

I have a WPF Ui and when the user clicks the only button I simply want to do some processing in a different thread and not lock the ui. Pretty simple little test for me as I'm learning.

Comment: Well yes, because `handler` is a local variable within the constructor. You haven't *got* a property... you'd have the same problem if you were dealing with any other type.

Comment: Right...so I create a delegate property to expose it?

Comment: Well you could. I'm not sure whether it's a good design, because we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well it's not clear why you need a property... why not just `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)MyXClass.GenerateViewMethod);`

Comment: ...cause I didn't know / think of / realize I could have easily cast it into an action like that. What you suggest is what I need. A property would not be the proper way to go.

Comment: I know you have like a bajillion points but you did answer it if you want to make it formaL I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your current code doesn't work is that `handler` is just a local variable within the constructor.

While you *could* add a public property, if the point is just for external code to be able to get a delegate which calls `GenerateViewMethod`, you don't need anything extra for that - the other code can just use a method group conversion. For example:

```
Action action = MyXClass.GenerateViewMethod;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```

Or:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) MyXClass.GenerateViewMethod);
```

Or if you're using [`DispatcherExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherextensions), you can simply use:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(MyXClass.GenerateViewMethod);
```

The reason the `DispatcherExtensions` class helps here is that the methods declared by `Dispatcher` itself only take `Delegate` parameters, so the compiler needs to be told what kind of delegate to build. The extensions take the specific `Action` delegate, so the compiler just converts the method group to that.

Comment: As usual a very robust and educational answer. Thank You.